# Should I say "my dog and my cat have very different personality" or "my dog and my cat have very differnet animality"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I think "animality" sounds right as dogs and cats are animals, not person. However, I heard some native speaker use "personality" here. Which one is correct?

Comment: Personality in animals - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_in_animals

Comment: @Hachi, when do we use animality then?

Comment: Animality is used  referring to the “animal side” of people. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/animality

Comment: They have different *personalities* or different *animalities*.

Comment: @Zuriel I’m a native English speaker, and I’ve never heard of the word ‘animality’ before. So thanks for teaching me a new word!

Comment: For an example from literature, we have this comment from Jules Winnfield in _Pulp Fiction_: _"a dog's got personality. Personality goes a long way."_

Comment: You are missing a determiner, making both of those non-English formulations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While "personality" is usually applied to persons, it can be applied to other things as well. Organisations and animals can be said to have "personality", meaning the things that make them distinctive - moods, characteristics etc.

Animality is something different, meaning [the characteristics associated with being an animal](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/animality). A person can have animality if they act like an animal.

Also note that your pets have different "personalities", plural.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you *could* use **personality** with pets, because we anthropomorphise them.

Perhaps it would be more accurate to compare their [**nature**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nature), from Lexico:

> **2.1** The innate or essential qualities or character of a person or animal.
>   *I don't expect cats to be free of the wild instinct, that's an essential part of their nature.*

So you could say

> My dog and my cat have very different **natures**.

However, the word [**animality**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/animality) is more usually applied to humans:

> **1** Animal nature or character.
>   *a pre-human condition of animality*
>
> **1.1** Physical, instinctive behaviour or qualities.
>   *what attracted me to her was her animality*

Answer (score 0):

Personality. Keep it simple. Or, as an alternative, one could use "character", for, after all, personality is the collection of qualities that make character.